# Are plist file the correct choose in this case?

Tags: objective-c, plist

I am building an app which has more than 800 places, each with street, city, phone number and other info. I want to show this elements in a table view and then load a detail view. I have almost built the system but I was wondering how I can then load the coordinate and for example the phone number of this place. Let do an example:
if the user press the 5th row, I want to pass the data from the 5th row of this plist to the detail view.

Is there any tutorial or advice about this? :)

Comment: If there's such amount of data, why don't you use an SQLite3 database instead?

Comment: dispaly ur plist..file

Comment: @H2CO3 that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I suggest using [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for this

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a fair amount of data. Instead of a plist, use an SQLite3 database to store it.

Comment: I am not very practice with database and so on. Can you explain a little bit more please? Very grateful :)

Comment: @patapple What do you mean by?

Comment: @patapple That's something Google can help you with.